# jQuery html function doesn't work with object as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application the html for picture is saved in `itemConfig.picture`

If I add the following code to js:

```
$('.picture').html(itemConfig.picture);
```

The div with class *picture* remains empty.
But this one works:

```
var tmpVar='<div class="field field-name-field-picture field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/ae/sites/default/files/DSC_02911_0.jpg" width="130" height="120" alt="" /></div></div></div>'
$('.picture').html(tmpVar);
```

These info would be useful:

```
alert(typeof itemConfig.picture); // returns "String"
alert(itemConfig.picture); // returns <div class="field field-name-field-picture field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/ae/sites/default/files/DSC_02911_0.jpg" width="130" height="120" alt="" /></div></div></div>
```

Why passing object property doesn't work?

Comment: I think when you do `$('.picture').html(itemConfig.picture);`, `$('.picture').length` is `0`. Can you check it & post here?

Comment: can you show code together? not split. maybe where you are writing `$('.picture').html(itemConfig.picture);` itemConfig.picture has different value

Comment: also remove the `alerts`, use `console.log` instead!

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? [Have a look here to learn how o debug JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). Overall there is not enough information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Are you sure typeof itemConfig.picture is String (kapital S). What browser are you using for this output. I know that .html throws an error when doing something like `$($("h1")[0]).html(new String("hi"))` but type of new String would be object and not String.

Comment: You can pass Object as a parameter [http://jsfiddle.net/mRbMZ/](http://jsfiddle.net/mRbMZ/)

Comment: FYI, you cannot say that you are passing an object. You want to pass the value of a property of an object. That's something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you but it's just a guess.

```
$('.picture').html(itemConfig.picture.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need `.toString()` as you can see in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYNH4/).

```
var itemConfig = {};
itemConfig.picture = "<div style='width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: red'></div>";

$('#start').on('click', function () {
    $('#type').html(typeof itemConfig.picture);
    $('#length').html($('.picture').length);
    $('.picture').html(itemConfig.picture);
});
```

The assumptions of the comments seem to be correct. You either don't have an element with the class `picture` in the dom (`picture.length = 0`) at this very moment or the the value of `itemConfig.picture` is something else.